# Recorrer checkbox seleccionados

Tags: c#, checkbox

Mi problema es el siguiente: a la hora de eliminar, selecciono con un **checkbox** los registros que voy a eliminar, pero a cuando presiono el botón **"ELIMINAR"** y después, cuando aparece el **messagebox**; este no elimina, es decir, se "despalomea" y los registros quedan en donde están. ¿Qué solución me dan?

```
private void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int fila = dataGridCategoria.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(c => Convert.ToBoolean(c.Cells[0].Value) == true).Count();
            if (fila > 0)
            {
                string mensaje = "Desea eliminar " + fila + " registro?";
                if (fila > 1)
                {
                    mensaje = "Desea eliminar " + fila + " registro?";
                }
                if (MessageBox.Show(mensaje, "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    for (int i = dataGridCategoria.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        DataGridViewRow filas = dataGridCategoria.Rows[i];
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(filas.Cells[0].Value) == true)
                        {
                            categoria = new Categoria();
                            categoria = dbSistemaGestion.Categorias.Find(i);
                            categoria.isDelete = true;
                            dbSistemaGestion.SaveChanges();
                            listarCategoria();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No termino de comprender donde estarias borrando. Porque veo que volver a instanciar Categoria, pero ese objeto donde va? Deberias quitar de tu arreglo el elemento seleccionado.

Comment: Creo que deberías de sacar el método listarCategorias del bucle for, ponlo fuera de las llaves.

Comment: Eh intentado sacar el "listarCategorias" fuera del bucle for pero no me funciono.